# Visual Studio 2012 RTM, Cannot debug .Net older than 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I have downloaded and installed the RTM version of Visual Studio 2012 from Microsoft. If I target any version of .Net other than 4.5 in any application I cannot debug that app. When I hit F5, it shows this dialog:

[image]

As you can see, I'm using it in Windows 8. The interesting thing is that if I see this dialog, even if I change the project to target .Net 4.5 after it shows this dialog, I won't be able to debug it. So basically I can debug an app as long as it is set to .Net 4.5 and this setting has never been changed.

Is there any solution to this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Have you changed the settings in `Project -> <Project name> properties -> Debug` ?

Comment: It is the debug version but you can debug a release version if your debugger works. You just debug an optimized version of your app. And might not hit some breakpoints or see variables. That's not the problem here.

Comment: I'm not talking about debug/release version. I was thinking more about the remote debugging options.

Comment: I tried some of them but which one specifically do you suggest me to change?

Comment: The runtime target version is most likely not direectly related to the message, but more a project setting that defaults differently in a VS2012 created project and older ones. Try comparing a "blank" project created with each.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Visual Studio do you have ? Express Edition isn't compatible with "desktop" projects, only with Metro style apps (so it's not only related to .Net target version)

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god, Man, I exactly had the same error! VERY FRUSTRATING! I have found a workaround though, here it is:

Go under your project's folder, and find the "bin" folder in it, the go into "debug" folder and delete everything from there! VS 2012 must be closed when you do this.

Debug worked for me afterwards.

Repeat and rinse with all other projects you have this issue with, and spread the word!

Hope it helps.
Cheers.